# How to edit a remote file with implicit su-ing to another user on remote host

Tags: linux, ssh, unix, text-editors, sudo

I want to edit files on Unix/Linux servers from my PC (running Linux and/or Windows). However due to security, I cannot log into the remote server as the file owner, but as my named user, then `sudo su` to file owner and then get the directory and file listing and edit the file.

Is there a editor or plugin for any editor that could connect to remote machine and execute needed commands after doing `sudo su -`? Or something similar?

Comment: Emacs can do it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4725727/113848

Comment: Is there any reason to do `sudo su user` instead of `su user`? Or `sudo su` instead of `sudo -i` or just `su`?

Comment: @terdon - Unfortunately, yes. We have to do sudo since that way users enter their own password to switch to another user.

Comment: @legoscia - thanks, i was planning on learning emacs. but i'm more used to vi.